# Converting ex-list Object to list in Storm

Tags: java, apache-storm

I'm currently working on Storm.

In Storm, for those of you might not know, it takes in whatever value types and emits as object type.

My problem is, I need to work with lists; should be able to access each item by index. But it would end up sent as an object anyway.

I have tried converting ex-list object to String type, parse each item by ", " and stored it in another list as a countermeature. It works fine but it looks like a messy way.

Another way I have tried was simply type cast the object to list. It has no compile errors, but the new list only has size of 1, and the only item in that list is the ex-list object that I need to convert to.

How can I convert ex-list object to list in sophisticated way?

I'm sorry if this is a juvenile question, and thanks in advance.

---

To inform you specific, the following snippet is the situation that converting has to happen.

```
public class TridentSpoutTest implements IBatchSpout{
    emitBatch(...) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("This");
        list.add("is");
        list.add("test");

        collector.emit(new Values(list));
    }
}

public class TridentFuncTest extends BaseFunction {
    public void execute(TridentTuple tuple, TridentCollector collector){
         OrdinaryClass.put(tuple.getValueByField("data"));   
         //getValueByField returns value in Object type
    }
}

public class OrdinaryClass {
     public void put(Object o) {
         //How to convert o back to list?
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as your list-type implements `Serializable` there should be no problem. Let's assume a Spout emits a lists and a bolt receives it:

```java
// Spout.nextTuple()
public void  nextTuple() {
    List<String> l = new ArrayList<String();
    l.add("a");
    l.add("b");
    l.add("c");
    // l gets stored at index zero
    collector.emit(new Values(l));
}

// Bolt.execute()
public void execute(Tuple input) {
    // receive from index zero and cast
    // (cast to ArrayList<String> would also work)
    List<String> l = (List<Array>)input.getValue(0));
    // you can access "a", "b", and "c" via l.get(0), l.get(1), l.get(2)
}
```

In your case, you need to use the proper types and add a cast (similar to my example):

```java
public class OrdinaryClass {
    // if it's a list, you type List (or ArrayList, LinkedList if you know the concrete list type)
    public void put(List o) {
    }
}

// for calling "put" add cast to proper type
OrdinaryClass.put((List)tuple.getValueByField("data"));
```

Comment: I'm so sorry Matthias. I was very excited to try out your code snippet and which worked nicely on input tuple variable, however it doesn't work on Object values still.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work on Object values" ? Can you update your question with a code example. What is the concrete problem? Do you get an exception?

Comment: I don't get any exceptions really. When I reach list value that's wrapped in Tuple, proposal methods related to List pop up just fine on eclipse.  Instead, when I convert object value that's been returned from tuple.getValueByField() to List type and do some List work, eclipse shows no proposal methods that has to do with List. And sorry for not being concrete. I'm learning to questioner here.

Comment: Just extended my answer. If you use type `Object` you can of course not use the variable as a list: you need to use the proper type, ie, `List`. You should work through a Java text book or programming tutorial; your problem is not related to Storm. Seems you are new to Java.

Comment: Thank you Matthias. I was hoping for any slight chance of solving this quesion in natural way, but seems like I should get my hands back dirty.

Comment: What do you mean by "natural way"?

Comment: Matthias, I'm not sure if you'll be able to read this comment that I chilled my head for couple of days and when I faced your code and tested it again, it is just the right answer I was looking for. I hope no one gets misleaded from my previous replies. And of course, thanks to you a million times.